Is it possible to run LSP diagnostics across the whole worksapce?
My LSP config works perfectly for the current buffer, but sometimes I just want to check the whole project and find all problems. I know that folke/trouble.nvim could show workspace diagnostics, but how to collect it in one command?
My projects are using typescript

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Expounding on @artemave's answer, the workspace-diagnostics.nvim plugin sends the textDocument/didOpen events from neovim's LSP client to the language server for all files in the workspace. It does so by simply looping over each file in the workspace (via git ls-files, which doesn't seem like the most robust solution) and sending the command to the server. It is activated inside the on_attach callback inside the lspconfig setup() function for the corresponding language.
It is fully explained in the author's post.

This plugin should do the trick https://github.com/artemave/workspace-diagnostics.nvim

A little bit of an explanation how it does the trick would greatly improve your answer.

Answers containing only links do not answer the question: https://vi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer
